# Change css to the element which has animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a css animation set up for a image as shown below:

```
<style>
 #egg{

  height:50px;
  z-index: 2;

    margin-left:950px;
    margin-top: 450px;
    position:absolute;
    animation-duration: 6.4s;
    animation-name: slide;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes slide{
    0% {
    margin-left: 910px;
  }

  49.99% {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
        transform: scaleX(1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
  50%{
    margin-left: 1250px;

        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
  100%{
    margin-left:910px;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
}
</style>
```

Normally I use the code below to change the css of the element:

```
$(element).css('margin-left','+=1000px');
```

But this is not working anymore for the element with animation. So I wondered how to change css margin to the element has animation attached?

The reason I'm doing this that when a button is clicked, the element should be show up in the middle of screen to start animation. but using margin:x% will damage the animation, sos I need to detect the window height and width thus adjust the margin dynamically.

Comment: You want to target the element that *has* an animation style, regardless of wether or not the element is currently animated or not? One has to wonder why you wouldn't just add the style with CSS, or target the ID, not to mention why you would change the left margin with javascript, when that's one of the styles your animating ?

Comment: @adeneo just edit the question about why I need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse current integer value and then add to it what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = $("#change-margin");
  setTimeout(function() {
    var current = parseInt(element.css('margin-left'));
    element.css('margin-left', 100 + current);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#change-margin {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="change-margin"></div>
```